# The referenced OpenAccessContext or 'IObjectScope' is already closed (UnsynchronizedPMProxy)

Tags: telerik, sitefinity

I am doing some background thread task in sitefinity. previously i was getting exception at the line.

Config.Get().ConnectionStrings. To overcome it i have sent dummy ashx request to my site and able to get connection string and connect ot db.

Now when trying to access DynamicContent via code

```
DynamicModuleManager dynamicModuleManager = DynamicModuleManager.GetManager();
            Type itemType = TypeResolutionService.ResolveType(key);
            DynamicContent item = dynamicModuleManager.GetDataItem(itemType, id);

            return item;
```

I am getting above mentioned error.

Any idea how to overcome this The referenced OpenAccessContext or 'IObjectScope' is already closed (UnsynchronizedPMProxy). error?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to try this approach to get the connection string:

```
var connectionString = Config.Get<DataConfig>().ConnectionStrings.Values.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks Veseline. 
I have already tried it but not work always. For instance if i am starting some background task in application start then it throws error (unless make that thread sleep for a while)

Comment: In this case the Config may not have been initialized. Make sure you do it in Bootstrapper.Initialized event. More about it here:
http://www.sitefinity.com/documentation/documentationarticles/developers-guide/sitefinity-essentials/modules/ecommerce/processing-hooks/preprocessorder-event